# Copy the content of all folders into one folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, directory

I have hundreds of folders with files in them. Is there any easy way to copy all files from these folders to one single folder? A command or application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Robocopy to do it. I have used below code before. There are many options with robocopy so you might  want to modify it to your requirement.  [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

```
@echo off
set source="C:\SOURCE_DATA_DIR"
set destination="C:\DESTINATION_DIR"

for %%F in (%destination%) do set destination="%%~fF"

for /r %source% %%F in (.) do if "%%~fF" neq %destination% ROBOCOPY "%%F" %destination% *.* /COPYALL /R:0
```